# Cannot show data in Bootstrap navs

Tags: html, angularjs

I am doing a project in `AngularJS` with `Bootstrap 3`. Currently, I have three `navs` with their respective id's as shown below:

```
<div class="tab">
  <ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li class="active"><a href="#pane1" data-toggle="tab">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#pane2" data-toggle="tab">Tab 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#pane3" data-toggle="tab">Tab 3</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="pane1" class="tab-pane active">
      <h4>The Markup</h4>
      <pre>Code here ...</pre>
    </div>
    <div id="pane2" class="tab-pane">
    <h4>Pane 2 Content</h4>
      <p> and so on ...</p>
    </div>
    <div id="pane3" class="tab-pane">
      <h4>Pane 3 Content</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When `panel1` is clicked, it should show the contents related to `panel1`. similarly to other two. But when that link is clicked, it will redirect to home page.

Comment: Please provide a fiddle or plunkr. Seems like neither you are using Bootstrap javascript nor Anular UI bootstrap

Comment: http://embed.plnkr.co/NKoz0F/preview